# Не загружает картинки по ссылке с 69.media.tumblr.com, ошибка Connection timed out

Tags: php, url, get, img

Пример картинки из Tumblr:

```
https://69.media.tumblr.com/ec3874e541a767ab578495b762201a53/tumblr_ph9je0Akck1r89eh5o1_1280.jpg
```

Скрипт:

```
<form method="get">
Введите URL:<br>
    <input type="text" name="url"/>
    <input type="submit" value=" загрузить "/>
</form>


<?php
 $name = md5(date('Y-m-d H:i:s').rand(0, 1000));
 $folder = 'upload/'; //в какую папку сохранять
 $source = ($_GET['url']);
 $dest = $folder.$name.'.png';

 copy($source, $dest);
 echo 'http://mysite.example/'.$folder.$name.'.png';
?>
```

С других ресурсов загружает нормально.

Нашла тут на сайте:

If you can view the image in a browser that is on the same machine as your program, then it might be that the server won't send the picture unless you look like a user rather than a program. In that case, modifying the browser identification string might fix your problem.

If you cannot view the image from a browser running on the program's PC, you will need to look elsewhere for the source of your problem.

Похоже, проблема в этом, Tumblr показывает изображение браузеру, но не отдаёт его скрипту для копирования. Как это исправить? Как сделать "modifying the browser identification string"?

На другие ресурсы картинки с Tumblr грузятся нормально, на imgur например.

Comment: Всего лишь Роскомнадзор заблокировал